# CakePHP - Different session timeouts in different controllers

Tags: php, session, cakephp, timeout

In my CakePHP application, I have multiple controllers with different purposes. On each controller, i want to have different auth session timeouts (for security purposes). So, in the first controller, I want the user to time out after 15 minutes, while users on the second controller should time out after 24 hours. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller add beforefilter method

```
public function beforeFilter(){
 Configure::write('Session.timeout', 15);
}
```